# Prevent multiple MessageBoxes on one thread without blocking

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have registered an error handler in my application that shows a user dialog MessageBox when an unhandled exception occurs. It's connected to the Application.DispatcherUnhandledException event and thus happens on the UI thread. Now I've seen a situation where an exception is thrown regularly, once per second, and new dialogs kept popping up. I was trying to prevent this with a lock, but since it's all on the same thread, this doesn't have any effect. An additional sleep lock on the same thread obviously led to a single blocked MessageBox on the screen.

The MessageBox seems to free the UI thread for other MessageBoxes to appear. How can I prevent that without blocking the thread?

The user has the choice to continue or exit the application. When continuing, the next queued MessageBox should appear, it should not be discarded. If too many messages show up in a time, the user can still decide to exit the application.

Comment: 'Ping! Ping! Ping! Ping! Ping!......

Comment: Exactly. In Visual Studio I have the Stop Debugging button, but the common user will remain very helpless.

Comment: IIRC, if a message-handler pops up an error messageBox, the box gets focus and runs its own message-loop.  This does not seem to prevent yet more messages that have been posted to the original window from being dispatched to it, and so generating yet more error boxes.  I agree that this is a PITA and tends to fill the screen with a carpet of annoying boxes. I'm afraid I don't know any way of stopping such behaviour other than keeping error-state info. to prevent the exception from happening multiple times.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this situation but I have 2 suggestions that may help: 1. use a static field somewhere and set/check it right before the messagebox pops up. 2. write your own custom messagebox so that it does not block the thread.

Comment: I do have a static field, but that doesn't help me in queuing further execution without blocking. (BTW, it should remain compatible with .NET 2.0.) But maybe I'll replace the MessageBox with a custom Form where I can add up further errors for the user to browse through them.

Comment: Time to stop displaying message boxes and acknowledge that the user has no hope of continuing to use the program in a meaningful way.  Terminate the program.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not with the message box. It is that what happens when the message box is still open, while another exception has occurred. In which case, your `DispatcherUnhandledException` handler gets re-entered on the *same* thread.

However, the user hasn't made a decision yet about the *previous* error, the previous message box is still waiting for his input. Your call stack looks like this:

```
=> DispatcherUnhandledExceptionHandler (current)
MessageBox.Show
DispatcherUnhandledExceptionHandler (previous)
```

Clearly, you cannot return from `DispatcherUnhandledExceptionHandler (previous)`, without returning from `DispatcherUnhandledExceptionHandler (current)` first: you're inside a nested call on the *same* thread. And you cannot return from `DispatcherUnhandledExceptionHandler (current)` without confirming this fist with the user, back to the egg.

I can think of just one way of solving this, while sticking with your question requirements. It's to display the message box on another thread and block the main thread's message loop while waiting for the user's choice. This way, no more exceptions can occur on the main thread, until you obtain the user's consent regarding the current exception:

```
Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += (s, e) =>
{
    this.IsEnabled = false; // disable the main window
    try
    {
        var result = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => MessageBox.Show(
                e.Exception.Message, "Continue?", 
                MessageBoxButton.YesNo),
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Result; // this blocks
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            e.Handled = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        this.IsEnabled = true; // enable the main window
    }
};
```

This is ugly from the UI experience prospective, but it gives you the desired workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Message boxes are still windows that run on your thread, so they have to pump window messages (a Modal Message Loop) in order to be repainted when required, moved, handle keyboard input (e.g. Tab to move between controls), mouse input. They still dispatch messages to *other* windows on the same thread, to ensure that the window that owns them is repainted. The owning window is disabled, so input messages simply result in the default sound being played, but timers will still be fired and any sent or posted messages will still be processed.

The usual source of such problems is that you have a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` or WPF `DispatcherTimer` attached to the window. Other possibilities include background threads using `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` to perform some operation on the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem situation. What solution would you like to propose? I can't find it in your answer.